# Excel 2010 VBA , looping with vlookup

Tags: vba, vlookup

I having issues with using vlookup in my Excel 2010 VBA

I want to loop through each cell in a column that is blank and look up a value from the neighbouring column from a data source.  I want to do this in a loop.  I have looked in many forums and can get this to work properly.

heres a sample of my code

```
Sheets("NPT(hrs)").Activate
Dim NumberRows As Integer
NumberRows = Range("a:a").Find("*", Range("A1"), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
NumberRows = NumberRows

ActiveCell.Offset(2, 69).Activate
For RowNum = 1 To NumberRows
    If Len(Range("BQ1").Offset(RowNum, 0)) = 0 Then

        ActiveCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(RowNum, 68), "Equipment!A:K", 7, False)

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    '' This approach never workedXXX
    'v = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(RowNum, 68), "Equipment!A:K", 7, False)
           ' ActiveSheet.Cells(RowNum , 69).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(Cells(RowNum,68) ,Equipment!A:K,7,false)"
    'ActiveCell.Text = "v"


    'MsgBox "fin work?"
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick code block that I wrote to replicate what I think you're trying to get at.

I created some sample data. The lookup on the right has unit prices and on the left you have a table with some entries missing in the 'total price' column.

[image: Excel screenshot of sample data]

The code block below loops through the cells in column C and runs a vlookup each time it finds a blank cell.

```
Sub FillInBlanks()

  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C21")

  For Each cell In rng
    If IsEmpty(cell) Then
        cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],R1C7:R11C8,2,FALSE)*RC[-1]"
    End If
  Next cell

End Sub
```

Running this macro should give you this

[image: Excel output]

Comment: Thanks,  I tried it out but my range for data to be looked up is on another sheet and this seems to have issue with that